# user_team is not associated to team

Tags: database, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize as a user and I use the 'many to many' option in the team situation. I created my code but : user_team is not associated to team! i am getting error how can i fix it. I'm doing it for a task, I would be very happy if you help me.tanks

If the structure is also wrong, can you tell me what my mistakes are?

userteam.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const UserTeam = sequelize.define(
    "user_team",
    {
      user_team_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: false,
        references: {
          model: "user",
          key: "user_id",
        },
        onDelete: "cascade",
        onUpdate: "cascade",
        unique: "unique-team-per-user",
      },
      team_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: false,
        references: {
          model: "team",
          key: "team_id",
        },
        onDelete: "cascade",
        onUpdate: "cascade",
        unique: "unique-team-per-user",
      },
    },

    { timestamps: false, tableName: "user_team", underscored: true }
  );

  UserTeam.associate = (models) => {
    UserTeam.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "user_id",
      targetKey: "user_id",
      as: "User",
    });
    UserTeam.belongsTo(models.Team, {
      foreignKey: "team_id",
      targetKey: "team_id",
      as: "Team",
    });

   
  };

  return UserTeam;
};
```

user.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "user",
    {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },

      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    { timestamps: true, tableName: "user", underscored: true }
  );

  User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.Todo, {
      as: "todos",
      foreignKey: "userId",
    });

    User.hasMany(models.Team, {
      as: "teams",
      foreignKey: "admin",
    });

    User.belongsToMany(models.Team, {
      as: "TeamsForUser",
      through: models.UserTeam,
      foreignKey: "user_id",
    });
  };

  return User;
};
```

team.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Team = sequelize.define(
    "team",
    {
      team_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      teamName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      admin: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },

    { tableName: "team", underscored: true }
  );
  Team.associate = (models) => {
    Team.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: "user",
      foreignKey: "admin",
    });
    Team.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      as: "UserInTeam",
      through: models.UserTeam,
      foreignKey: "team_id",
    });
    
  };
  return Team;
};
```

controller.js

```
const getAll = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const myTeams = await Team.findAll({
      include: [{ model: UserTeam }],
    });
    myTeams.forEach((element) => {
      console.log(element.get());
    });

    return res.status(200).json(myTeams);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

Comment: Just check if you call `associate` method for all registered models and also please show the Sequelize query that cases this error.

Comment: @Anatoly  I added the function that gives the error

Comment: and says associate is undefined  how can ı solve

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem

just add to index database config js

```
db.users.belongsToMany(db.team, {
  as: "teams",
  through: "user_team",
  foreignKey: "user_id",
});

db.team.belongsToMany(db.users, {
  as: "users",
  through: "user_team",
  foreignKey: "team_id",
});

enter code here
```